# Is it possible to import invoice records via the Paypal API

Tags: paypal

I can see from the [paypal API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#invoicing) that its possible to create records of invoices and mark those as paid.

Does this cost money?

I have paper records of invoices (<1000) that have been taken over the previous 3 years, Could i use the API to "import" this history of invoices so that old invoices are searchable etc in the same way as new invoices / payments that will be taken via paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to send an API call to obtain invoice details and search invoices. Most likely you will not be able to go back further than 2 years.  You will need to submit an application request for 3rd Party permissions in order to send an API call to obtain this information. Here is the link to [apply for third party permissions](https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications):

Here are the [Invoicing API Examples](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/InvoiceAPIExamples/?mark=Invoice%20API):

From the above PayPal Documentation:

> **Searching for Invoices**
>
> This example searches for invoices using `SearchInvoices.` You must have
>   created the original invoice either for yourself or on behalf of
>   another merchant.
>
> PayPal can return a maximum of 100 invoices per page. In this example,
>   only the first 10 invoices that you created using the Invoicing
>   Service API for the jb-us-seller1@paypal.com account are returned:

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/SearchInvoices \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: Your_API_username" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: Your_API_password" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: Your_API_signature" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: Your_AppID"  \
  -d requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US \
  -d merchantEmail=jb-us-seller1%40paypal.com \
  -d parameters.origin=API \
  -d parameters.email=jb-us-seller1%40paypal.com \
  -d page=1 \
  -d pageSize=10
```

From the PayPal Documentation here is an example of obtaining Invoice
Details:

> **Obtaining Invoice Details**
>
> This example gets information about an invoice using
>   `GetInvoiceDetails`.

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/GetInvoiceDetails \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: Your_API_username" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: Your_API_password" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: Your_API_signature" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: Your_AppID"  \
  -d requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll \
  -d requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US \
  -d invoiceID=INV2-RVY9-UWTW-64HZ-BR9W
```